# No suitable driver found snowflake JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm currently working on an application. We are moving off our file systems and over to our Snowflake database. I can't seem to make a connection to the database - I am continually met with "no suitable driver found" error.

The correct driver was loaded and installed into the build path. *Does anyone know whats going on?*

The code:

```
package com.GriefUI.DBComponents;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Snowflake_Driver {

public static void databaseConnection(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedOperationException{


    try {

        Connection connObject = getConnection();
        Statement stmt = connObject.createStatement();
        ResultSet rSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE");


    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}


 private static Connection getConnection()
          throws SQLException {
        try {
          Class.forName("net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
          System.err.println("Driver not found");
        }

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        String user = "user";
        String pwsd = "password";
        String connectStr = "jdbc:snowflake://My_Environment.snowflakecomputing.com";

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr, user, pwsd);
        return conn;
      }

 }
```

Build path:

[image: Build path]

And the related stacktrace:

```
Driver not found
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:snowflake://My_Environment.snowflakecomputing.com
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at com.GriefUI.DBComponents.Snowflake_Driver.getConnection(Snowflake_Driver.java:54)
at com.GriefUI.DBComponents.Snowflake_Driver.databaseConnection(Snowflake_Driver.java:20)
at com.GriefUI.Servers.PushServer.doPost(PushServer.java:60)
at com.GriefUI.Servers.PushServer.doGet(PushServer.java:47)
```

Comment: From where did you get that name? Shouldn't that be `com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver` instead?

Comment: I got it from their example in their documentation

Comment: I would suggest then to inspect the registered drivers that you have, loop over `DriverManager.getDrivers()` and print them all, see if you have it. Probably the `com.` one is an old version (or viceversa).

Comment: I did that, and it appears no drivers are being loaded/read by eclipse

Comment: In my case, it was invalid database URI. Correct URL pattern is "jdbc:snowflake://myorganization-myaccount.snowflakecomputing.com/?user=peter&warehouse=mywh&db=mydb&schema=public".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The research I would suggest taking a look at is: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html

This answer also looked helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54504514/12127815 
"adding the jar to classpath, and then running the following command, Class.forName("provided driver name") in the calling class? "
Though a light jar has been asked to be an an enhancement here: "[open]Light driver jar? #174" https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/issues/174

Integrating the driver to a project: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-download.html#integrating-the-driver-into-a-project
Specific information copied from the documentation: "To integrate the driver into a project, add the necessary tags to your pom.xml file. For example:

```html
<groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
<artifactId>snowflake-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>3.9.2</version>
```

Where the  tag specifies the version of the driver you wish to integrate. Note that version 3.9.2 is used in this example for illustration purposes only. The latest available version of the driver may be higher."

Others may have better insights.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error message may be misleading.

In my case, Snowflake server is behind a firewall/proxy and I get the same error when connection cannot be obtained physically. It all works on the server all right - I get the error when trying to connect to the DB from my local machine that is on the opposite side of the firewall.

So, make sure your application can physically connect to the DB or use a proxy parameter in your java launcher, such as

`-Dhttp.proxyHost=a-proxy.host.domain.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080` or similar